# Flurry SDK (viPhone SDK 7.2.1) for iPhone giving duplicate symbol clang error while running on simulator Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, clang, flurry

I am getting below mentioned error while running the application on simulator with libFlurry_7.2.1.a:

> duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
>   .../Flurry/libFlurry_7.2.1.a(PLCrashReportTextFormatter.o)
>   .../Flurry/libFlurry_7.2.1.a(PLCrashReportMachExceptionInfo.o) ld: 110
>   duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

but when i replaced the lib file with "libFlurry_6.5.0.a" it is running on simulator.

Comment: Please check there exists single flury lib in the project

Comment: yes there is single flurry lib , it is working with libFlurry_6.5.0.a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using an older version of xCode? If so you'll need to use Flurry iOS v7.1. This is the last version that will work with xCode versions less than 7.

You can find more details here:
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/